# org export filter on escaped characters

Tags: org-export

I was thinking about this question: [Configuring org-export to replace LaTeX def macros](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24458/configuring-org-export-to-replace-latex-def-macros)

It seems like you should be able to convert latex macros in org export using an export filter. e.g., in the linked question, convert `\R` to `\mathbb{R}`. However, I can't figure out the syntax. I tried:

```
(require 'ox)
(defun my-latex-filter-r-macro (text backend info)
  "Replace \\R with \\mathbb{R}"
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\R" "\\\\mathbb{R}" text)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-plain-text-functions
             'my-latex-filter-r-macro)
```

And then exported the following org file to html:

```
* This is a headline
  Here I refer to \R in normal text.
```

However, the \R is not altered in export. I've tried different numbers of backslashes, with no success - 0, 1, 2 or 3 backslashes, and every `r` except for the escaped `\R` is converted to `\mathbb{r}`. With 4 or more backslashes, none of the `r` characters gets converted. So it looks like escaped characters are protected from export filters - is this so? Is ther anyway to pre-process escaped characters in org export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter `org-export-filter-plain-text-functions` never sees `\R`, try to filter `org-export-filter-latex-fragment-functions`.
For example, this works for me:

```el
(require 'ox)
(defun my-latex-filter-r-macro (text backend info)
  "Replace \\R with \\mathbb{R}"
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\R" "\\\\mathbb{R}" text)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-latex-fragment-functions
             'my-latex-filter-r-macro)
```